# Why is 'angular' not defined in a separate controller file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I declare an Angular module in one file, `App.js` like this:

```
hookPointApp = {};
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var hookPointApp = angular.module("hookPointApp", ["ngResource"]);

    hookPointApp.controller("rootController", [
        "$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {

            $scope.getCurrentUser = function() {
                $http.post("/Account/CurrentUser", {
                    ....
                    .then(function(data) {
                            $scope.currentUser = angular.fromJson(data.data).Id
                        },
                    ...
            };
            $scope.getCurrentUser();
        }]);
})();
```

This seems to work, I get no errors reported when it loads and runs the function. Then, in a separate `Areas.js` file, I try to declare a controller for the module, like so:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module("hookPointApp").controller('AreasController', ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
        ....
    };
```

Both files declare their stuff in self executing functions, and my scripts are referenced like so, at the bottom of the `body` element:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
<script src="~/Scripts/App/App.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/App/AreasController.js"></script>
```

Where the `angular` bundle contains 'official' Angular modules, and the other two will be bundled when I can get them working nicely. When I execute the line:

```
angular.module("hookPointApp").controller('AreasController', ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http)
```

in `AreasController.js`, I get an error that says

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
> ```

Yet the Angular bundle is referenced, and I would expect, to be rendered before the conventional script references. What am I missing here, or doing stupidly?

Just for more info, the `angular` bundle is defined like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
    "~/Scripts/angular/angular.js",
    "~/Scripts/angular/angular-resource.js"));
```

Comment: Nothing obvious in code shown. Same issue in multiple browsers?

Comment: @charlietfl It seems to work in Edge, but gives the same error in IE 11. But thanks for the heads-up: I found one peripheral function that didn't work in IE.

Comment: Hookpointapp is not defined in your app.js, you assigned the module to hookpoint. But that should result in an error already, copypaste typo?

Comment: @Noppey, Indeed, I left off the global variable declaration at the top that you can see now. I'm quite against globals, but was trying everything. I think I will just chain everything for now, until I can get individual files working.

Comment: No need to chain... using `angular.module` as getter is far preferred over using global variable and shouldn't in theory pose any issues. Seems very odd that angulr not defined because it is indeed a global

Comment: Yeah, I gave up on chaining, too messy, and used `angular.module` blocks in the same file that I initially construct the module.

Comment: In App.js included before Areas.js you have no issues with angular being undefined? If so then something had to set angular to undefined in you code. But from the code here I cannot see nothing obvious.